# php linkedin api not working

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I found a repo:
https://github.com/mahmudahsan/Linkedin---Simple-integration-for-your-website

in copied the OAuth.php and linkedin.php files and put my api key and secret into it and here is what I'm getting:

```
My Profile Info

  404
  1454454187300
  N0JYR99YQA
  0
  Could not find person based on: ~


Performing search for: ?company-name=facebook&count=10
Search URL: http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,site-standard-profile-request,headline),num-results)?company-name=facebook&count=10

Look people who worked in facebookSimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [status] => 403
    [timestamp] => 1454454187323
    [request-id] => DTH9GFLY2T
    [error-code] => 0
    [message] => People search must be done on behalf of a member.
)
```

any idea what i could be doing wrong?